# Offset Rotation Calculations in .NET2

Tags: .net, math, matrix, rotation, trigonometry

I wondered if someone can help me out with this problem I have.   I am using .NET 2 environment.

I have 2 points at different locations on a 2D plane as two PointF

I have a known  rotation (in Degrees) at the first point, I need to know how to calculate what that rotation will be at the second "offset" point.

In other words, I want to rotate the second point by an unknown amount but the effect at the first point needs to be the known rotation value.

I have tried all sorts to solve this puzzle, my math and trig skills are rather rusty.  Can anyone help me out?

Many thanks.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to accomplish. When you say "rotate" are you rotating about the origin? Do you want Point#2 to rotate about Point#1? A picture would be really helpful. I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hopefully this will help:   http://i55.tinypic.com/68ev5x.jpg

I am trying to calculate what the rotation will be at point B (which is a known offset from Point A) when a known rotation is applied to point A

More specifically I have two systems trying to communicate offsets measured as X, Y and Rotation.   However the two systems use different rotation points, so I need to apply some sort of rotation correction.

Comment: So you want to rotate Point A about some other point, call it Origin A. And then you want to rotate Point B about some other point, call it Origin B, so that when it's done, the B's location relative to A hasn't changed?

Comment: No, I am trying to translate a rotation value calculated around one point to a rotation around a separate point on a known X and Y offset.

Comment: But that's not possible in the general case. For example, rotating the point at `(10, 10)` around the origin will result in points that are not possible to reach when rotating around, say, `(12, 23)`. There will have to be a translation component, as well.

Comment: Can you expand on this further please?   I'm looking to understand better the problem, and how to tackle soloutions (but will happily take pseudo code!)

Comment: @George: You can clearly see that a translation is needed because if you rotate around point a then the point a will not move. however, any rotation around point b will either not move anything or move point a, neither of which are correct (assuming a non zero rotation around a).

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to translate a rotation value calculated around one point to a rotation around a separate point on a known X and Y offset.

I interpret that as meaning you have a third point, let's call it point R, that rotates x degrees around point A.  You want to figure out how many degrees around point B that R has rotated.

Framed that way, it's [not possible](http://tinypic.com?ref=runqiu).  The rotation circle around point A (red) is different than the rotation circle around point B (blue).  The two black arrows illustrate that when you say "rotate around point A" and "rotate around point B" they take you in different directions.